# Is it possible to hide the cursor in a webpage using CSS or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to hide the cursor when showing a webpage that is meant to display information in a building hall. It doesn't have to be interactive at all. I tried changing the cursor property and using a transparent cursor image but it didn't solve my problem.

Does anybody know if this can be done? I suppose this can be thought of as a security threat for a user that can't know what he is clicking on, so I'm not very optimistic... Thank you!

Answer (score 255, accepted):

With CSS:

```
selector { cursor: none; }
```

An example:

```html
<div class="nocursor">
   Some stuff
</div>
<style type="text/css">
    .nocursor { cursor:none; }
</style>
```

To set this on an element in Javascript, you can use the `style` property:

```
<div id="nocursor"><!-- some stuff --></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('nocursor').style.cursor = 'none';
</script>
```

If you want to set this on the whole body:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.body.style.cursor = 'none';
</script>
```

Make sure you really want to hide the cursor, though. It can *really* annoy people.

Comment: That worked perfect! The curious thing is that I snooped the W3C specification (http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/ui.html) and they didn't say anything about that. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think the W4 officially endorse it - it's one of those 'extensions' which every single browser supports, for some reason.

Comment: W3 rather!  World *World* Wide Web.

Comment: How to care about browsers that do not support CSS3:
Use a `1x1` px transparent png or 1% transparency png.

Comment: @Darek: Does IE6 support transparent PNGs in cursors? Or would it work better with a transparent GIF?

Comment: To my knowledge IE6 supports transparent PNG, as long as it is real transparency and not alpha channel transparency. If in doubt, check yourself with the test suite: http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/pngsuite.html.

Comment: How can I undo `document.body.style.cursor` to make it visible again?

Comment: @MatthiasHerrmann: Try `document.body.style.cursor = 'auto'`.

Answer (score 49):

## [Pointer Lock API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Pointer_Lock_API)

While the `cursor: none` CSS solution is definitely a solid and easy *workaround*, if your actual goal is to *remove* the default cursor while your web application is being used, or implement your *own* interpretation of raw mouse movement (for FPS games, for example), you might want to consider using the [Pointer Lock API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Pointer_Lock_API) instead.

You can use [requestPointerLock](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/requestPointerLock) on an element to remove the cursor, and redirect all `mousemove` events to that element (which you may or may not handle):

```
document.body.requestPointerLock();
```

To release the lock, you can use [exitPointerLock](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/exitPointerLock):

```
document.exitPointerLock();
```

---

### Additional notes

**No cursor, for real**

This is a very powerful API call. It not only renders your cursor invisible, but *it actually removes your operating system's native cursor*. You won't be able to select text, or do *anything* with your mouse (except listening to some mouse events in your code) until the pointer lock is released (either by using `exitPointerLock` or pressing <kbd>ESC</kbd> in some browsers).

That is, you cannot leave the window with your cursor for it to show again, as there is no cursor.

**Restrictions**

As mentioned above, this is a very powerful API call, and is thus only allowed to be made in response to some direct user-interaction on the web, such as a click; for example:

```
document.addEventListener("click", function () {
    document.body.requestPointerLock();
});
```

Also, `requestPointerLock` won't work from a sandboxed `iframe` unless the `allow-pointer-lock` permission is set.

**User-notifications**

Some browsers will prompt the user for a confirmation before the lock is engaged, some will simply display a message. This means pointer lock might not activate right away after the call. However, the actual activation of pointer locking can be listened to by listening to the `pointerchange` event on the element on which `requestPointerLock` was called:

```
document.body.addEventListener("pointerlockchange", function () {
    if (document.pointerLockElement === document.body) {
        // Pointer is now locked to <body>.
    }
});
```

Most browsers will only display the message once, but Firefox will occasionally spam the message on every single call. AFAIK, this can only be worked around by user-settings, see [Disable pointer-lock notification in Firefox](https://superuser.com/questions/1209306/disable-pointer-lock-notification-in-firefox).

**Listening to raw mouse movement**

The Pointer Lock API not only removes the mouse, but instead redirects raw mouse movement data to the element `requestPointerLock` was called on. This can be listened to simply by using the `mousemove` event, then accessing the `movementX` and `movementY` properties on the event object:

```
document.body.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
    console.log("Moved by " + e.movementX + ", " + e.movementY);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I found this the only reliable means of banishing the cursor in a SPA when switching to a fullscreen slideshow.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to hide the cursor in the entire webpage, using `body` will not work unless it covers the entire visible page, which is not always the case. To make sure the cursor is hidden everywhere in the page, use:

```
document.documentElement.style.cursor = 'none';
```

To reenable it:

```
document.documentElement.style.cursor = 'auto';
```

The analogue with static CSS notation is `html {cursor:none}` (or, depending on what exactly you want [`* {cursor:none}` / `:root {cursor:none}`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60680887/)).

Answer (score 2):

I did it with transparent *.cur 1px to 1px, but it looks like small dot. :( I think it's the best cross-browser thing that I can do.
CSS2.1 has no value 'none' for 'cursor' property - it was added in CSS3. Thats why it's workable not everywhere.

Comment: Use a 1% transparency .png/.cur instead.

Answer (score 2):

For whole html document try this

```css
html * {cursor:none}
```

Or if some css overwrite your cursor: none use !important

```css
html * {cursor:none!important}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it in CSS:

```
#ID { cursor: none !important; }
```

Comment: You should generally avoid `!important`.