# Hide Mouse Cursor when it's within HTML5 Canvas Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm in the process of making a game using Javascript and the html5 canvas element as an alternative to Flash. My question is: is there any bit of code I can use to hide the mouse cursor/pointer as it passes within the canvas?
Help is much appreciated!

Comment: Related (shameful plug): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1071363/is-it-possible-to-hide-the-cursor-in-a-webpage-using-css-or-javascript

Answer (score 21):

I don't think you need Javascript for this, you can just use CSS.
Assign your canvas a div id/class, and then use this in your CSS template:

`* {cursor: none;}`

Comment: This is part of [CSS3](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-ui/#cursor) but not part of [CSS2](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/ui.html#propdef-cursor).

Comment: This does not work on the latest Firefox on Linux. The cursor gets hidden for the rest of the page, but still shows up over canvas.

Comment: Changing the cursor for all elements (`*`) is not a good approach.

Answer (score 9):

You can use javascript to manipulate cursor style. Code:

```
<div id="canvas_div_no_cursor">
   <!-- canvas here -->
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById('canvas_div_no_cursor').style.cursor = "none";
</script>
```

Comment: I tried this, but it only seems to work in firefox. Also, I could not get the CSS to work for some reason, I believe it too only works in firefox. Does anybody know if there is a cross-browser solution? I appreciate all of your help.

Comment: @Chris: It works in IE9 and Firefox 4.0 as I tested. Opera 11 and Google Chrome don't hide cursor. (Maybe some security settings restrict this).

Comment: @Chris Google chrome is hiding cursor for me when jQuery is used `$('#canvas_div_no_cursor').css('cursor', 'none')

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way (on modern browsers) is to set the cursor to `none` on the canvas.

If your canvas is created in HTML, do:

```
<canvas id="canvas" style="cursor: none;"></canvas>
```

I would favour this over a style-sheet because you want to guarantee the cursor value is not over-ridden.

If your canvas is created in JavaScript, do:

```
const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.style.cursor = 'none';
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
```

Answer (score -1):

Select the canvas element:

```
 canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
```

Get context :

```
context = canvas.getContext("2d");
```

Set none :

```
context.strokeStyle = none;
```

Comment: none has to be string ("none"). Anyway it didn't work for me.