# How do I convert this css to javascript

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, cursor

I want to hide the cursor for my browser based game. I don't want to do this until the game starts.

I have this in CSS: `* { cursor: none }`. How would I do this in JavaScript? My target browser is Chrome and only Chrome.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1071356/is-it-possible-to-hide-the-cursor-in-a-webpage-using-css-or-javascript#1071363

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
document.body.style.cursor='none';
```

A note about your CSS : it's better to avoid as much as possible the `*` selector, especially when you can just set a style to the body.

Comment: please not that this is equal to `body{ cursor:none }`. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4256372/1149495) if you want to use the `*` selector in JavaScript

Comment: @WouterJ The good solution here is probably to avoid using `*`.

Comment: yes, I know. That's why I added it as a comment and not as an answer.

Comment: @dystroy Using the body does not work for hyperlinks (as an example, might not work for other objects too....hence why I want the * selector)

Comment: I thought this was for a full window game, which made some sense... Do you really really want to hide the cursor over the links and the inputs ? Is the goal to piss the users ?

Comment: @dystroy what I am doing would not affect the users (who will watch an induction video anyways), other that aesthetics.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="nocursor"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('nocursor').style.cursor = 'none';
</script>
```

It still uses css, but I assume that this is what you were looking for.