# Blinking Cursor Appearing on Input Type File HTML Element in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer, file-upload

I have the following HTML elements on my page:

**Profile.html**

```
<img id="imgDefault" title="Upload Profile Photo" src="/Images/DefaultPhotoMale.png" style="z-index: -99999999; cursor: pointer; width: 120px; height: 120px;" />

<input type="file" id="fileImgUpload" name="files[]" onchange="fileSelectHandler('home','false')" accept="image/gif, image/jpeg,image/jpg,image/bmp,image/pjpeg,image/png" title="Upload Profile Photo" style="width: 120px; height: 120px; opacity: 0; float: left;" tabindex="1" />

<input type="text" id="txtName" placeholder="Name" maxlength="50" tabindex="2" />

<input type="text" id="txtSurname" placeholder="txtSurname" maxlength="50" tabindex="3" />
```

The problem here is that when I start run this in Internet Explorer and press the `Tab` key on my keyboard there is a cursor which blinks on the fileImgUpload element. Since the cursor looks ugly, I don't want to show it but I am unable to do so. Can anyone please give me the solution to this problem? I wouldn't mind if the solution to this problem will require me to edit my `.css` or `.js` file. Please note that the cursor appears only in Internet Explorer and not in other browsers such as Firefox or Chrome.

Replies at the earliest will be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You could try turning off the tab index.  That seems to be forcing focus to tabindex 1.  Perhaps put another field into a 0x0 div, and set the tabindex to be on that field.

Comment: Thank you very much for replying. I have tried removing its tabindex as well as removing all the tabindices on the page but it's still not disappearing.

Comment: What about setting the tab index to something else?

Comment: That won't work either because when I set the tabindex to -1, the tab focus won't come over there at all. I want the tab focus to come over there but I don't want the blinking cursor to get displayed.

Comment: Upon dropping this into a test page myself, it seems that no matter what your tab indexes are, the last field you have focus on gets the cursor.  But it seems that creating a hidden field with the tabindex of "1" will take the focus on the initial load.  In IE8, anyway.

Comment: This might help too:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1071356/is-it-possible-to-hide-the-cursor-in-a-webpage-using-css-or-javascript