# Hide Cursor doesn't work (CSS)

Tags: html, css, web

My question is quite similar to another one on Stack Oweflow, however the answer on the other question didn't help me.

So I tried to hide the cursor on a webpage by writing following code in my stylesheet:

```
* { cursor: none; }
```

It works fine on some parts of the website but in other parts you can see it.
Anyone had a similar problem and/or knows the answer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to hide the cursor in a webpage using CSS or Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1071356/is-it-possible-to-hide-the-cursor-in-a-webpage-using-css-or-javascript)

Comment: @Luciano No, I don't want to do it in Javascript, that is unnecessary

Comment: Read the answer again, it uses CSS and gives the option of using JS

Comment: @Luciano No read my question again. I already have the "cursor: none;" but it doesn't works. And like I said, I don't want to use JS for that. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It will still show on elements, that have their own `cursor: ...` defined.

You can use `* { cursor: none !important; }` to avoid this and make it work ... but some might say never use `!important`

Comment: This is actually one of the few cases that warrant the existence of `!important`.

Comment: Oh thanks! You have no Idea how long I searched for an answer.

Comment: @MaëlWyssbrod that's why we help you ; )