# hide mouse cursor in html page

Tags: javascript, html, cursor, hide, mouse

I want to hide the mouse cursor in HTML5 screens deployed on self-service machine with Elo touchscreen. I followed the steps of https://stackoverflow.com/a/1071363.The first time it works fine but when I restart the machine, then the cursor is appearing back again. I've noticed that it is hidden once you touch the screen and it's shown up again once a new screen is loaded.

Have anyone faced this problem again.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at Elo touchscreen's driver/settings, you'll find the answer there how to turn cursor off

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to hide the cursor in a webpage using CSS or Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1071356/is-it-possible-to-hide-the-cursor-in-a-webpage-using-css-or-javascript)