# What selector i can use to select mouse pointer object?

Tags: javascript, html, automation, cursor, mouseevent

I try to control the mouse movement, but I don't understand how I can select the mouse pointer object.

Comment: Selector? Like CSS selector?

Comment: There's no selector for the cursor, it's not a HTML element.

Comment: AFAIK you cannot directly control the mouse. Only pretend to control it by hiding the mouse and then creating a fake mouse in its place. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1071356/is-it-possible-to-hide-the-cursor-in-a-webpage-using-css-or-javascript