# A-frame show mouse pointer with a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, three.js, aframe, webvr

I am currently using a scene using A-frame (https://aframe.io) where I am hiding the mouse pointer in my scene. How can I create something where when a function is issued, my mouse pointer will show and when another function occurs, my mouse pointer will hide.

Currently the dfeault is that my mouse pointer is hidden. I want it so that when a function called "showPointer" occurs, my mouse pointer will show again and when a function called hidePointer occurs, my mouse pointer will hide again. How can I acheive this. My functions:

```
<script>
function hidePointer() {
//hide mouse pointer
}

function showPointer() {
//show mouse pointer 
} 
</script>
```

Comment: See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1071356/is-it-possible-to-hide-the-cursor-in-a-webpage-using-css-or-javascript

Comment: I'm guessing the code for this problem is completely different than that issue because of the fact that I am trying to show or hide a cursor in a webvr environment rendered in 3d rather than a 2d webpage.

Comment: Is `look-controls="pointerLockEnabled: true;"` helpful?

Comment: Not exactly because instead of keeping the pointerLock in a fixed state of being hidden or  not I want to be able to show or hide the pointer depending on a function so it's not in a fixed state.

Comment: @Aidan Young: Why would it be different?

Comment: Well for starters, the link is using css to hide the cursor when I need to use JavaScript.

Comment: Javascript alone is not able to hide your cursor. It is a style ultimately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
function hidePointer() {
  $('a-scene').canvas.style.cursor='none'
}
            
function showPointer() {
  $('a-scene').canvas.style.cursor='pointer'
  // replace "pointer" with other style keyword
} 
</script>
```

more detail about cursor style, check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor)

please make sure canvas element rm class a-grab-cursor from canvas

remove with this `$('a-frame').classList.remove("a-grab-cursor")`

check detail [here](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/b164623dfa0d2548158f4b7da06157497cd4ea29/src/style/aframe.css#L52-L56)

if you using 'cursor' component, please disable [mouse cursor styles enabled](https://aframe.io/docs/1.2.0/components/cursor.html#properties_mousecursorstylesenabled)

Answer (score 0):

```js
const fullBrowserWindow = document.querySelector(`body`);
const popupElement = document.querySelector(`div.popup`);

function hidePointer() {
  fullBrowserWindow.style.cursor = 'none';
}

function showPointer() {
  fullBrowserWindow.style.cursor = 'default';
}

popupElement.onmouseenter = (event) => {
  showPointer();
  console.log('Mouse entered the div, Pointer Shown!');
};

popupElement.onmouseleave = (event) => {
  hidePointer();
  console.log('Mouse left the div, Pointer Removed!');
};
```

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  cursor: none;
  background-color: #ff0000;
}
body div.wegbl {
  width: 480px;
  height: 312px;
  background-color: #000000;
}
body div.popup {
  width: 200px;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>No Cursor - on when mouse is over popup</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="webgl"></div>
    <div class="popup">Popup Promt? [Y/N]</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The code works perfectly but uses css to hide the cursor and doesnt hide the cursor on a function. I need to hide the cursor with a javascript function. When the function occurs, the cursor should be hidden, and when another function occurs, the cursor should show again.

Comment: Javascript doesn't have an API which hides the cursor (to my knowledge), it is in the css property cursor set to 'none'. even in A-frame they use set canvasElement.style.cursor = 'none' when you apply look-controls="pointerLockEnabled: true;"

Comment: I'm trying to do the opposite however, I want to hide my cursor at all times but when a object in my scene is clicked a 2d popup is triggered. I'm wondering how I can hide my cursor as a default so when I'm hovering over my popup which is a div with the class of Popup1 the cursor should show.

Comment: check the solution, I have altered it. `I want to hide my cursor at all times` => cursor: none; css-property is on the body element of the html page(this means the cursor is always hidden) => the popup can be a div with position: absolute; and when the mouseenter/mouseleave events are triggered on top of the div you show hide the cursor, check the modified snippet, please. Thanks!